# Bootstrap rendering text with an image within a row and col

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to render text below an image, i'm having truble stopping the text pushing down on the col below making the current overall grid mess up.

All I would like to do is keep the grid ratio. I have run some tests using class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" this works fine with the text and images but will only have 4 objects in a line.

If i use the 6 objects in a line class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" the text will not render correctly messing up the page.

Example of grid working when the text is not to long:

[image]

Example of the grid messing up when the text is to long overlapping the bootstrap col:

[image]

Image used: [image]

Code used:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink0" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test Tester tester tester</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink8" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink9" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink10" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; text-align:center; font-size: 160%;">
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink11" runat="server" Visible="true" NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank" style="color: rgb(0, 130, 86);"><img class="img-responsive img-portfolio" src="/images/text.png" alt="" width="500" height="250">Test</asp:HyperLink> 
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp
Try this examples. 
Assume that the page has a size of 12. Place the division for each. <Div class = "col col-sm-2">

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0RW0MH6Q0LD

Comment: In this code i insert the div with row to create a new line and 
divided the number of columns

Comment: That is what happens with floated elements of different heights. If you know how many elements there are per row, you can solve it by clearing the float on the appropriate elements. Or you switch to a solution that uses inline-block instead of float.

Comment: I currently have a fixed version but using the new row after 6 objects but, i'm now moving to auto generated objects where i don't know how many objects are going to populate the grid. I could somehow create a count function so after 6 objects within the loop, add a new row etc. But that's a slightly different matter of course. because all I wanted to know if it was something that could just be fixed using bootstrap rendering alone. But the inline-block method sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the grid breaking when your text gets too long is because you need to reset the columns. At the end of the last column in the row you will need to add a clearfix div, information for which can be found on this page > [Responsive Column Resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

I have taken bits of your code to show you where the clearfix div needs to go:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
      <p>Test Tester tester tester</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
</div>
```